Every abelian group can be embedded into a ring
Let $(G,0,+)$ be an abelian group. Does there always exist a ring with unity $(R,0,1,+,\cdot)$ and an injective homomorphism of groups $ \psi:(G,0,+)\rightarrow (R,0,+)$?
Is this hard to prove, or are there simple proofs?

Can’t you just define the multiplication to be trivial ($xy=0$ for all $x,y \in G$)?

but in this case, the ring will not have a unity

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80227/constructing-a-ring-from-an-abelian-group-in-a-minimal-way

Let $R=\mathbb Z\oplus G$, with $(m,g)\cdot (n,h):=(mn,mh+ng)$. Then $R$ is a unital ring with identity $(1,0)$.
